# No simple UTF8 support in latex?

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, latex-misc

The following should look good in your browser, AND compile in Latex looking beautiful right?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
UTF-8 test:
\begin{verbatim}
logic:  not:¬
        and: ∧  nand:⊼
        or: ∨   nor:⊽
        inequal to, xor:≢,≠,⊻,⊕     equal to: ≡,=
Set logic:  ∪,∩,⊊,⊋,⊆,⊇,⊈,⊉,≡ 
    avoid useage of non-specific: ⊂,⊃,⊄,⊅
Set Membership:∈,∉,∌,∋,∅
assignment ≔≕
predicate logic:∃,∄,∀,∴,∵
regex: /|\.⋆^?+(){,}[]
Arrows: ↖↑↗⇖⇑⇗
        ←↔→⇐⇔⇒⇕↕
        ↙↓↘⇙⇓⇘
        ↚↮↛⇍⇎⇏
numbers:ℕatural={0,1,2,3, … ∞}, ℤintegers,
        ℚ=rational, ¬ℚ=irrational,
        ℝeal, ±∞, ℂomplex
size: ≤,≥,<,>,≮,≯,≰,≱,≪,≫,≢,≠,≡,=
Greek Alphabet:
ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣ ΤΥΦΧΨΩ
αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρσςτυφχψω
Game:
Chess symbols:♚♛♜♝♞♟♔♕♖♗♘♙
Playing card symbols:♠♣♥♦ 23456789JQKA
miscellaneous:°∙■□▪▫○●☇
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Currently(2010 Dec 12 with latest ubuntu with all updated packages) I get the following error:

`! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:**"insert random char here"** not set up for use with LaTeX.`

Comment: @GlassGhost: If you rewrote your question without such an accusative tone (as seen especially in your last comment), people would probably be more willing to help out.  TeX can certainly be frustrating, but there's no reason to take that out on the community.

Comment: @GlassGhost I challenge you to find a better method than TeX/LaTeX to produce a paper as beautiful as http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1007/1007.3722v3.pdf and as easy as using LaTeX (including the interactivity on the fig 3). If you want to typeset beautiful documents you found the right community to help you. If you want to type something that is ugly, typographically wrong and mediocre you can buy Word, hey you can even use the arial font.

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides where did I say that Latex is not beautiful? I merely stated that it was not compiling.

Comment: @GlassGhost: I believe I speak for most of us when I say that we do not appreciate the thinly veiled sarcasm and a certain note of entitlement in your comments. The community is happy to help anybody who comes around with a question, even those of the LMGTFY variety. But you need to show a certain degree of respect for people who spend their (free) time answering your questions.

Comment: @Martin Tapankov I believe that you do not "speak for most of us" while veiled sarcasm may exist; LMGTFY doesn't solve the UTF8 problem, in fact the solution(currently) is to use a different dialect of latex, and even then there is a lot of characters that can be missing. I AM SORRY if I am NOT used to my latex looking BEAUTIFUL.

Comment: @Martin: (slightly off topic), I'm now glad that I googled LMGTFY myself, instead of asking you what that stood for.

Comment: I don’t see any  veiled sarcasm or accusative tone. And yes, it **sucks** that TeX is oblivious of Unicode, twenty years after the fact. So just to offer a different opinion, I’m completely fine with the question as-is.

Comment: @GlassGhost: A small, but important, point: LuaTeX and XeTeX aren't dialects, they're implementations.  It's more like someone suggesting Chrome instead of Firefox, or GCC instead of Microsoft's C compiler.  You're still writing in (La)TeX, HTML, or C, respectively, even if there are extensions.  LaTeX itself is arguably a dialect of TeX, though perhaps descendant would be be a better term.

Comment: @GlassGhost: My intention was not to imply that your question is easy to solve -- you managed to pull my words out of context. The UTF-8 issue is important for me as well, I've had my fair share of problems with proper Cyrillic support in (La)TeX. However, I think you might want to reconsider in the future the way you formulate your posts (not their content, though). I refuse to be involved in any further discussion on personal grounds.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The original TeX engine wasn't designed to handle multi-byte encodings. So any package that provides Unicode functionality on top of that  has to be imperfect. There are however two new engines that do provide full Unicode support: [LuaTeX](http://www.luatex.org/) and [XeTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX). There is also a package that makes it easy to select any OpenType or TrueType font for use with these engines: [`fontspec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec). (There is also [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) which provides support for Unicode-aware math fonts like [STIX](http://www.stixfonts.org/) (or [XITS](http://ctan.org/pkg/xits)) and [Cambria Math](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=360), but it is still in heavy development and not quite complete yet.)

Be aware that the version of these engines and packages shipped with Ubuntu 10.10 (and earlier) are very outdated. If you want to use them, you have to manually install [TeX Live 2010](http://tug.org/texlive/) (which is easy).

After you have updated, you can use `lualatex` or `xelatex` to compile the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
% your example here
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

This sets `FreeSerif` as the main font ([Free Serif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_UCS_Outline_Fonts) isn't the most beautiful font, but I do not know any other free font that rivals it in Unicode coverage; it comes preinstalled with Ubuntu -- in fact your browser probably uses it to display the symbols) and `FreeMono` as the monospace font ([Free Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_UCS_Outline_Fonts) lacks the chess symbols and diagonal implication arrows, but provides everything else in your example; Free Serif would provide everything but isn't monospace). Another free font family with good Unicode coverage is [DejaVu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts), which as based on [Bitstream Vera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream_Vera). The compiled document looks as follows:

[image: example]

You could of course replace `\setmonofont{FreeMono}` by `\setmonofont{FreeSerif}`. Then your `verbatim` text wouldn't be monospaced anymore, but would contain all symbols. See the [`fontspec` manual](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) for other fancy things that are possible.

If you are writing a text that mixes several languages and scripts then a single font will probably not cover all possible symbols. In this case the [`polyglossia` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) will come in handy (it currently only works with XeLaTeX).

Comment: your answer seems to be the best, if you remove that giant image from it, I'll mark it as accepted. Also I thought that UTF8 or Unicode supports most languages, is this not true?

Comment: @GlassGhost: It does, but most fonts only implement a tiny subset. So if you want to mix say Chinese and Arabic text, you will need a font that has Chinese characters and a font that has Arabic characters. It is rather unlikely that you will find a good font that has both of them.

Comment: @GlassGhost: If you rewrite your question to be more concise and less accusing, I will remove the picture.

Comment: @Caramdir: I think the image proves the concept and should stay.  Don't sacrifice useful information for 15 rep points.

Comment: @Matthew I won't. However, if the question is formulated more concisely with a smaller example, I will adapt the image to the question. Most of the example symbols are math symbols which should be set in math mode, so actually the image could be slightly misleading.

Comment: @Caramdir should the verbatim be taken away? Oh and I marked your question as accepted anyways, I shouldn't have argued rather; suggested the fact after accepting your answer, which is what I am now doing

Answer (score 9):

inputenc with option utf8 knows definitions only for a subset of unicode. And from this subset it will only load a small subset as default. If you want more definitions you should load the corresponding font encodings. If you want full unicode support use a unicode enabled engine like xetex or luatex (but I have some doubt that you will find many fonts with chess support).

Answer (score 5):

For Unicode support, you need to use [XeTeX](http://tug.org/xetex/).  It supports using UTF-8 encoded files by default. The [Wikipedia page on XeTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX) is also useful.

Comment: Or LuaTeX, see my answer. It supports UTF-8 encoded documents also by default.

Answer (score 4):

Here is your example which can be compiled using XeTeX or LuaTeX. Deja Vu Sans Mono contains all occurring characters except for nand, nor and xor:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
°±∞∙■□▪▫○●
Set Membership:∈,∉,∌,∋,∅
Set logic:
    ∪,∩,⊊,⊋,⊆,⊇,⊈,⊉,≡ 
    avoid but don't be frightened of usage of non-specific: ⊂,⊃,⊄,⊅
assignment≔≕
logic:
    and: ∧
    nand:⊼
    or: ∨
    nor:⊽
    not:¬
    inequal to, xor:≢,≠,⊻,⊕
    equal to: ≡,=
size: ≤,≥,<,>,≮,≯,≰,≱,≪,≫
regex: ⋆
predicate logic:∃,∄,∀,∴,∵
numbers:
    ℂomplex
    ℝeal
    ℚ=rational
    ¬ℚ=irrational
    ℤintegers
    ℕatural={0,1,2,3,
Arrows:
↖↑↗⇖⇑⇗
←↔→⇐⇔⇒⇕↕
↙↓↘⇙⇓⇘
↚↮↛⇍⇎⇏

Greek Alphabet:
ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣ ΤΥΦΧΨΩ
αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρσςτυφχψω

Game:
Chess symbols:♚♛♜♝♞♟♔♕♖♗♘♙
Playing card symbols:♠♣♥♦ 23456789JQKA
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\begin{document}
 ... (your font list, but not verbatim, because arial is not a typewriter font) ...
\end{document}
```

with `lualatex`. There you go.

You will need a proper unicode font though.