# How do I use Delicious font in my beamer presentation

Tags: fonts, beamer

I want to use [Delicious](http://www.josbuivenga.demon.nl/delicious.html) font in my beamer presentation. How should I install this font and/or use it in my presentation. I am running ubuntu 10.04 and have installed the font. I am wondering how do I use this font in my beamer presentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default TeX engine cannot use system fonts directly; the font needs to be converted in a format that TeX can understand.

However, the newly developed engines XeTeX and LuaTeX can use OpenType fonts directly. You can adopt the [method from a previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/no-simple-utf8-support-in-latex/6998#6998) (with `\setsansfont` instead of `\setmonofont`).

Note that the version of `fontspec` included in Ubuntu 10.04 (the package is `texlive-xetex`) only works with `xelatex`. Also, it (and the Ubuntu XeTeX version) is rather old and might contain bugs. If something doesn't work, you should install [TeX Live 2010](http://tug.org/texlive/) directly.

Comment: To be fair, the TeXlive which comes as an Ubuntu package does include xelatex and the fontspec package in the `texlive-xetex` package, which are all that is needed here. (Though as you say, they are very dated.)

Comment: @frabjous: I was vaguely remembering that there was some critical bug in it, but it seems to work (at least in Ubuntu 10.10). I'll change the answer accordingly.

Comment: and frabjous. Thank you. I had xetex and fontspec package installed, but I will try it with TexLive2010 as suggested.

Comment: Actually Ubuntu 10.04 contains the Debian packages of TeXLive2009, which is more or less the original release. TL'09 was the first to have compatible versions of XeLaTeX and beamer.

Answer (score 4):

Put the fonts into the system font dir, which is on my Linux system `/usr/share/fonts/opentype` and then run with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Delicious}
\let\sfdefault\rmdefault
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Delicious}
 Some text with Delicious
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course you need to run `sudo fc-cache -fv` after putting the file in `/usr/share/fonts`. But suncoolsu says that the font is already installed, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @frabjous: no, I didn't run that command!

Comment: Or put it in `~/.fonts` to install locally for the user.

Comment: @everyone. I did what @caramdir suggests and did `sudo fc-cache -fv` as @frabjous suggests to install the font on my system. But @Herbert, I dont have the `opentype` directory. The directories I see are: truetype type1 and X11. However, I must remark, TexLive is being installed currently.

Comment: @suncoolsu: then create the `opentype`directory. It is not really needed but makes sense to have the fonts saved in proper directories

Comment: @Herbert. I did exactly what you suggested and I am sorry to say it did not work as expected. I could not reproduce your slide. I am sorry for my dumbness in latex/beamer but I am wondering how do I tell `pdflatex` to access the `Delicious` font in `opentype` directory. Also I use org-mode in Emacs to make beamer slides so my beamer knowledge is not up to the mark :-(

Comment: @suncoolsu: you have to run `xelatex`. Reading the other commands it seems unpossible with ubuntus texlive. I never used the texlive packages from SuSE or Ubunto, I _always_ installed the texlive from `http://www.tug.org/texlive`. It is much more easier to handle because I can have daily updates.

Comment: @Herbert. Perfect. Thank you very much. TexLive 2010 and compiling it using xelatex worked.

Comment: A remark: the above shown font is the bold variant. Don't know why this one is taken. The default Roman font is possible with `\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Delicious-Roman}`

Comment: @suncoolsu: yes TexLive from TUG is fun! You can get the updates with running `tlmgr --self --all update` if you installed as user or `sudo tlmgr --self --all update` if installed as root.